# Extracting data from bing maps to insert into custom data structures

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I'm currently using the Bing Maps API to display a map of a city along with traffic data (such as incident report and traffic flow).

I need to be able to pass a complete list of street segments and intersections of a given area to an AI application to work with. However, all this data, along with the corresponding traffic data I need seems to be bound to the actual map of the API (ie. It can only be displayed and not worked with). Is there any way to extract this information and insert it into a custom made data structure? If not, is there some other map API that is capable of doing this? (although I would prefer work with Bing Maps if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traffic data can only be used within the Bing Maps controls. This data cannot be extracted from Bing Maps and stored elsewhere. Try taking a look at the HERE Traffic API's: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic

Comment: The free trial subscription doesn't seem to include traffic data... :/